# Download avatars with one click (discord.js v13.6.0)

Tags: discord.js, avatar

I noticed there are links that open images of user avatars in the browser to view in full size, but for downloading need to make two more clicks (right click and left click to download the image), and there are those that, as soon the link opens in the browser, the image of user avatar download starts immediately.
View link example: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.id}/{avatar.name}.png?size=4096`
Immediately download example: `https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/(character_set_unknown_to_me)/%3Fsize%3D4096/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.id}/${avatar.name}.png`
Of course, I can get the second link by right-clicking on the open image in full size that is embedded in my `MessageEmbed().setImage()` and click copy the link given, but I want this link to also be inserted into `MessageEmbed().setDescription()` so that clicking on the link immediately opens the link of user avatar and starts downloading. I tried to do it myself but it just didn't work. On the Internet, I searched for what the second link was, but I didn’t find it, so I don’t even have a clue if it’s called anything other than a `embed.image.url`.